# How to loop between two pandas dataframes to select a range of rows to be extracted from dataframe2, based on a value given in the dataframe1 1

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two large data frames with prices for the same product. They data frames have different sizes.
The first data frame `df1`, has one price per product, the second data frame `df2`, has multiple prices per product. I need to get the product and price from `df1` and find the correspondent range of prices (-5.0 < price from df1 < 5.0) in df2.
Then extract this to a third data frame `df3`.

1. This is what I have:

   [image]
2. This is the code I´ve trying without luck:

   ```
   df3 = pd.DataFrame()
   for index, row in df1.iterrows():
       pr1 = float(row['price'])
       np1 = (row['product'])
       npd = MD + 2
       npu = MD - 2    
   for index, row in df2.iterrows():
       np2 = (row['product1'])

       if np2L == np1:
          df3 = df2[(df2.price1 <= npd) & (df2.price1 <= npu)]
          …
   ```

I also replaced the last line for: `df3 = df2.ix[npu:npd]`, but it still doesn't work.

Any advice on how to proceed?

Comment: Please add a reproducible example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# set index of df1 copy to product (since it is unique)
df1_c = df1.copy().set_index('product')

# join df2 and df1_c on df2.product1 = df1_c.product
df3 = df2.copy().join(other=df1_c, on='product1')
```

[image: df2-join-df1]

```
# select rows of df3 where absolute difference between price1 and price <= 5
df3 = df3[ abs(df3.price1-df3.price) <= 5.0 ].reset_index().drop(['index', 'price'], axis=1)
df3
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Samer, very elegant solution, with no looping. Thank you very much for you help. It worked like a charm. :)